# how and when to call SatisfyimportOnce

Tags: c#, mef

I am a newbie to MEF pattern, my qusetion is as follows.

When all should i call SatisfyImportOnce, right now i am calling it on my program.cs and pass the Form 1's reference to it.

```
static void Main()
        {
.
.
.

     var container = new CompositionContainer(new DirectoryCatalog(Environment.CurrentDirectory));
                container.SatisfyImportsOnce(frm1);
}
```

should i need to call every time before i an open a new form/dialog from  form1?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You would only need to call SatisfyImportsOnce on objects that have never had there imports statisfied. So only when you create a new Form would you need to call it on that object instance.

Do keep in mind that with SatisfyImportsOnce you will not get recomposition on those Imports which is where the "Once" comes from. That is the main difference between SatisfyImportsOnce and Compose.